# How would I conduct a relative risk meta-analysis, when the exposure levels in the data are presented in overlapping ranges?

Tags: meta-analysis, epidemiology, meta-regression, relative-risk

For example, if I have studies observing the dose-response relationship between alcohol (g/day) and breast cancer, and the exposures are reported as heterogeneous and overlapping ranges (10-20g, 15-30g), how would I conduct a meta-analysis to model the dose-response curve? Interested in any R packages that handle this, but also just the general theory behind addressing this problem.

I'm currently taking the midpoint of the range and feeding that data into standard meta-analysis models, but wonder if there are alternatives/literature that don't assume a 30-100 range is the same as a 60-70.

Comment: Do you know, or can you estimate, the distribution of doses overall before categorisation? Is this a licensed product which comes packaged in specific doses so you know they are multiples of a certain dose?

Comment: I wouldn't be able to derive the distribution of exposure from the studies. The closest I could get would be looking at survey data, and assuming the population between survey and the literature are the same. What did you have in mind?

Comment: Using population data might work. I have seen it done for age in studies of older people. Ignore the part of my comment about licensed dose I forgot you were looking at alcohol not a medicinal product.

Comment: I may be able to estimate the proportion of individual doses within each exposure range, but would still have to interpolate the RR of those individual doses. Not sure how to go about it